# Discrepancy in proposed solution to SR time difference problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I recently encountered a relativity problem. Suppose two points, A and B. They have a distance of $L$, which is proper length. Observer C, travels from A to B with the uniform speed of $0.8c$. As C takes off from A, he emits a light towards B, in the same direction he is travelling.

The question is asking to identify if the following is correct: In  Observer C's frame, the gap of time between the light arriving B, and B approaching C is larger than $\dfrac L{4c}$ (which is the time gap of C and the light arriving B, from A's frame).

I was doubting the given answer, so I consulted other people. That gave me conflicting answers.

The answer states that from A's frame, since the time gap of C and the light's arrival is proper time, from C's perspective, time dilation causes it to get larger (thus, the statement is correct). The latter states that, due to length contraction from C's perspective, the time gap decreases. (so no, it's wrong)

Which one would be correct, and can you add some details? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us work in the frame of AB here.

The time it takes for the light pulse to reach B is
$\dfrac Lc$

The time it takes for C to reach B is
$\dfrac L{0.8c}=\dfrac{5L}{4c}$

Thus, the time lapse between those two events is
$\dfrac L{4c}$

---

Now we work in C's frame.

The distance between A and B is now
$\dfrac L\gamma=0.6L=\dfrac{3L}5$

The time it takes for B to reach C is
$\dfrac{3L/5}{0.8c}=\dfrac{3L}{4c}$

The time it takes for the light pulse and B to meet is
$\dfrac{3L/5}{1.8c}=\dfrac L{3c}$

The time difference is now $\dfrac{5L}{12c}>\dfrac L{4c}$

We can thus see that the other person you asked is just wrong.

---

Let us check if the question setter is correct or not.

Since $\gamma\dfrac L{4c}=\dfrac{5L}{12c}$, it is at least plausible.

Because the light pulse reaching B is an event,
and B and C meeting is another event,
and in C's frame, C is not moving, just waiting,
so yes, C will be measuring proper time.

Which means that the time dilation argument,
even though it is very weird to apply it here,
is a correct argument.

It is too weird, though, and I would advise against trusting its use here.
It is, after all, easier to actually work out the details and get the correct answer that way.

Comment: I think that makes sense. But as a relative newcomer to using math in relativity I'd like to ask, when you derived the time it takes for light to meet B in c's frame, how did you come up with dividing the value with 1.8c? Should I add up the speed of light and the object?

Comment: Yes, they are moving towards each other. Since it is all in one frame, there is no need to transform the velocities, and we can just add.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm also curious, wouldn't that disapprove the second postulate of relativity?

Comment: No, it only says that the fastest ONE can go is $c$. If you look at the speed of one relative to the other, you will use the velocity addition formula, and see that it is not faster than $c$

Comment: Oh so you mean like this?: From the perspective of C, point B is approaching C at 0.8c. But since the speed of light is same to all observers, the light is still going forward at c. Thus, in the frame of C, the relative distance between the light and B decreases at 1.8c?

Comment: That is correct.